# MySQL sorts tables with one unique column automatically. Where is this documented?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm running MySQL 5.5 and found behaviour I didn't know of before.

Given this create:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UQ` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

With these inserts:

```
insert into test (name) values ('b');
insert into test (name) values ('a');
```

And this select:

```
select * from test;
```

MySQL does something I wasn't aware of:

```
2   a
1   b
```

It sorts automatically.

Given a table with one extra, non-unique column:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_column` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_UQ` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And the same inserts (see above), the select (see above) gives this result:

```
1   b   NULL
2   a   NULL
```

Which is kind of expected.

Where is the behaviour of the first query ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/848d5/1)) documented? I'd like to see more of these peculiar things.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does *not* sort result sets automatically.  The ordering of a result set is indeterminate *unless the query specifies an `order by` clause*.

You should never rely on any sort of "implicit" ordering.  Just because you see it in 1 (or 100 queries).  In fact, without an `order by`, the same query can return results in different orders on subsequent runs (although I'll admit that this regularly occurs in other database, it is unlikely in MySQL).

Instead, add the `ORDER BY`.  Ordering by a primary key is remarkably efficient, so you don't have to worry about performance.

Comment: I'm not saying I'm relying on this. I do clearly see a difference in behaviour between tables with one unique column and tables with a unique column and another random column. My question is whether this behaviour is defined anywhere or not.

Comment: @Sherlock . . . It *is* defined.  The result set is in indeterminate order unless you specify an `order by`.